# Do format string vulnerabilities exist in C# or Java?

Tags: security

I have found out about the format string vulnerability in C++, but C++ is an old language. I want to know whether the format string vulnerability still exists in modern languages, like C# and Java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Format String Vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_String):-

> Format string problems are a classic C/C++ issue that are now rare due to the ease of discovery. The reason format string vulnerabilities can be exploited is due to the %n operator. The %n operator will write the number of characters, which have been printed by the format string therefore far, to the memory pointed to by its argument.

However, languages such as C# and Java produce [managed code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code) that are not susceptible to memory address overwrites as the CLR/JVM manage the process memory rather than it being the responsibility of the developer. This can mean that a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) vulnerability is a lot less likely (but it can happen depending on 3rd party components being called or vulnerabilities in the languages themselves).

So the answer is no for managed languages such as C# and Java.